# How to represent directory of IzPack installer?

Tags: maven, izpack

I'm using Maven and IzPack. I'm looking for a way to put a file into the directory of the installer file. In the install.xml I've got a file tag set with a targetdir of "." but that will only work if the installer is executed from that directory. If executed from a different directory, the file is put in the current working directory of the user instead.

Having checked IzPack documentation, there's a built-in variable for $INSTALL_PATH, but I need the path of the installer. There's no way to predict where this installer will be when executed so specifying a pre-set directory won't work. Trying to specify the local directory via Maven just gives the path to the POM.

Is there an undocumented variable that would do the job or something else I've overlooked?

Comment: Why do you need the folder of the installer? Please show your full pom file?

Comment: It has to do with how the installer is bundled. I'm afraid I can't paste the full POM. I was just wondering if there was any way of representing the relative path of the installer.